# snap mounted `core20` as media

Tags: 22.04, snap, ubuntu-core

When I logged in today there was an icon in the dock that looks like I had plugged in an external drive.

After some investigation i found out that this is

```
$ mount | grep media
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core20_1587.snap (deleted) on /media/user/disk type squashfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,uhelper=udisks2)
```

I can open the drive and see the ubuntu system in there.

Is there a reason for this `core20` to be mounted there?

---

updates to answer questions from the comments:

#### `findmnt | grep core20`

```
├─/snap/kde-frameworks-5-91-qt-5-15-3-core20/1    /dev/loop16               squashfs            ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue
├─/snap/core20/1611                               /dev/loop7                squashfs            ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue
├─/snap/core20/1593                               /dev/loop32               squashfs            ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue
```

There is no entry for this in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: the file does indeed no longer exists, that is probably what the `(deleted)` means in the output of `mount`. but i can still access the contents: `ls /media/user/disk` lists files i would expect in an ubuntu installation.

Comment: That's completely weird, I can't tell you what happend and how the (non-existing) file could be mounted at that location. I'd try to unmount it (`sudo umount /media/user/disk`) and see what happens. Probably the file was mounted while it was going to be deleted, but the mount prevented completely deletion?

Comment: probably something like that. but even then; the mountpoint is completely weird... why would the system (or snap) mount something into my `/media` folder...?

Comment: i can umount it - but the icon in the dock stays and i can re-mount it by clicking on it...

Comment: While mounted run `lsblk -f`, maybe we can see something here.

Comment: `loop8 squashfs 4.0  0   100% /media/user/disk` ...nothing out of the ordinary, i'd say...

Comment: Doing sudo umount worked for me.

Comment: after i rebooted the drive was gone. but "did you try to turn it off and on again" is a bit... well...